# OSX how to set Skim "Check for file changes" in command line?

Tags: macos

I am using Skim to display PDF compiled by latexmk.

Currently, I am manually check the "Check for file changes" button in side Skim preference.

Can I use a command to set the configuration?
I have tried the bellow command, but it doesnot work for me.

```
defaults write -app Skim SKAutoReloadFileUpdate -boolean true
```

[image]

Comment: Try copying Skim's `plist` file with the button checked, and then again after unchecking it. Then compare the two `plist` files to see what Skim is doing itself. Copy that!

Answer (score 1):

Skim's `plist` file seems to be here on my machine with my version:

```
$HOME/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim.plist
```

You can dump the plist file with `PlistBuddy` like this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim.plist"
```

If I dump the file with the `Check for Changes` unchecked and then again with it checked, I can difference the files with `opendiff` and I get this:

[image]

So, it looks to me like you need to set `SKAutoCheckFileUpdate`, which would be:

```
defaults write -app skim SKAutoCheckFileUpdate '1'
```